# Calling springWs for validation of message from Camel

Tags: web-services, apache-camel, spring-ws

In my application, I have to validate the authorization of incoming message via calling a webservice.e.g if the user belongs to the authorised group then only process the message. For this, I have to build the authorizationRequest from one of the properties of the incoming message say userId(not the whole incoming message) and send to webservice.
I am new to camel. To achive this in a non-camel application I would have created a webservice client, make a call with userId(param) and process the response.
Main Camel route :

```
from( <URI> ).routeId("UpdateRoute")
                .process("AuthorizationProcessor")
                .process( "ValidateProcessor" )
                .choice()
                .when(matches(cond1)).to("cond1Processor")
                .when(matches(cond2)).to("cond2UpdateProcessor")
                .otherwise().to( "invalidconditionProcessor" );

    }
```

With Camel, I am calling a custom processor AuthorizationProcessor and making a webservice call as I can do in non camel application.
I am not utilising Camel properly.
What should be the appropriate way to make the webservice call .
I tried creating a route AuthorizationRoute and into I can use spring ws component to make the call.But not sure how this route will be invoked and where should I build the request.

Comment: What type of web service are you trying to deploy? REST or SOAP? Are you running camel as standalone or within a container like apache-karaf?

Comment: I want to build and send SOAP message to webservice.I am running Camel in Undertow. I have a property set in Exchange say userId .Now I have to call webservice for operation validateUserId expecting UserId in the soap request.

Answer (score 0):

Camel has a couple of components able to make Web Service calls (REST or SOAP). One of the most popular ones is [camel-cxf](http://camel.apache.org/cxf.html), which (you guessed it, uses Apache CXF to make WS calls.

There is a myriad of options available, but it boils down to including:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-cxf</artifactId>
    <version>x.x.x</version>
    <!-- use the same version as your Camel core version -->
</dependency>
```

And then in your route:

```
from( <URI> ).routeId("UpdateRoute")
  .to("cxf:http://address/service?serviceClass=com.MyClass")
  .process( "ValidateProcessor" ) // process the resoponse here
  .choice()
    .when(matches(cond1)).to("cond1Processor")
    .when(matches(cond2)).to("cond2UpdateProcessor")
    .otherwise().to( "invalidconditionProcessor" );
```

Comment: I think this solution will work for send the requestbody I have in the exchange. I have to build a new request and from the field I have in exchange and send to webservice.